# Get underlying low-level Kafka consumers and Producers in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have a usecase where I want to get the underlying Kafka producer (KafkaTemplate) in a Spring Cloud Stream application. While navigating the code I stumbled upon `KafkaProducerMessageHandler` which has a `getKafkaTemplate` method. However, it fails to auto-wire.

Also, if I directly auto-wire `KafkaTemplate`, the template is initialized with default properties and it ignores the `broker` in the `binder` key of the SCSt configuration

How can I access the underlying KafkaTemplate or a producer/consumer in a Spring Cloud Stream app?

**EDIT:** Actually my SCSt app has multiple Kafka binders and I want to get the `KafkaTemplate` or Kafka producer corresponding to each binder. Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear why you would need to do that, but you can capture the `KafkaTemplate`s by adding a `ProducerMessageHandlerCustomizer` `@Bean` to the application context.

Comment: Hi Gary. Thank you for your response. 

Unfortunately, `ProducerMessageHandlerCustomizer` was not added until SCSt 3.0. I am still using SCSt 2.2 and I cannot update. Is there any other way to capture the `KafkaTemplate`s?

Comment: No; sorry; there is not. Perhaps if you can explain your use case, there might be some alternative.

Comment: Is there a sample usage of `ProducerMessageHandlerCustomizer` documented anywhere, Gary?